# Input submit not working on iOS 6

Tags: ipad, ios6, input, shopping-cart, submit-button

I have an input submit button that is on this page: http://www.foxleyphotography.com/lbce

If you click on the 'Show Menu' tab and then 'Buy Prints' it is the 'Add To Cart' button that works fine on all other devices and browsers tested but not with iOS 6 (tested on iPhone 4S and iPad 3).

I just wondered if anyone knew why this button is doing nothing on those devices? All other input submits throughout the rest of the site work no problem on these devices. At first I thought it may be something to do with a z-index/absolute positioning error with another div interfering but having tried giving the button a ridiculously high z-index (it has relative positioning) this didn't work either.

The form itself works fine on the iPad - I tested it by updating the quantity field and then pressing 'Go' on the keypad of the iPad which updated the cart as it should so I don't think has anything to do with the processing code - just the button that doesn't want to work!

Hope someone can figure it out - I have searched until I'm blue in the face. Thanks in advance!